# как изменять excel документ

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtablewidget

Делаю приложение, которое открывает *excel* файл. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы на кнопку "добавить", открывалось окно, где нужно ввести данные и эти данные записывались в таблицу excel и так же удаление данных, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

main файл

```
from UI.table import Ui_table
import sys
import pandas as pd 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, \
QStackedWidget, QMessageBox
import openpyxl
 from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class StartMenuMain(QMainWindow, Ui_table):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(StartMenuMain, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self) 
    
    self.fname = None                                                            
    self.initUI()
    
def initUI(self):
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.update)
    self.action.triggered.connect(self.open_file)

def update(self):
    if not self.fname:                                                            
        QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Ошибка!', "Выберите Exсel файл")
        return                                                                  
           

    excel_file_path = self.fname                             
    worksheet_name = 'Лист1'                                     
    self.loadExcelData(excel_file_path, worksheet_name)

def open_file(self):
                                                          
    self.fname, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Выберите файл', '.',  
        "Файлы Exсel (*.xlsx)") 
    print(f'fname = {self.fname}')    
    



    
def loadExcelData(self, excel_file_path, worksheet_name):
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, worksheet_name)
    if df.size == 0:
        return

    df.fillna('', inplace=True)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(df.shape[0])
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(df.shape[1])
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(df.columns)

    # returns pandas array object
    for row in df.iterrows():
        values = row[1]
        for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
            if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
                value = '{0:0,.0f}'.format(value)
            tableItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row[0], col_index, tableItem)

    self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 300)
            


if __name__ == '__main__': 
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

startmenu_window = StartMenuMain()

windows = QStackedWidget()

windows.addWidget(startmenu_window)  # 0
windows.setWindowTitle("")

windows.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

table файл

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_table(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(1000, 684)
    MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1000, 684))
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 342, 131, 31))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 10, 811, 631))
    self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 220, 131, 31))
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 279, 131, 31))
    self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1000, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
    self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.action.setObjectName("action")
    self.menu.addAction(self.action)
    self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "обновить"))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "добавить"))
    self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "удалить"))
    self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "открыть"))
    self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "открыть файл"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается примерно так:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd 
import openpyxl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, \
    QStackedWidget, QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from UI.table import Ui_table
class Ui_table(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1000, 684)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1000, 684))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 342, 131, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 10, 811, 631))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 220, 131, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 279, 131, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1000, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "обновить"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "добавить"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "удалить"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "открыть"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "открыть файл"))
        

class StartMenuMain(QMainWindow, Ui_table):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(StartMenuMain, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self) 
        
        self.fname = None                                                            
        self.initUI()
        
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.addRow)                        # +++
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.delRow)                        # +++
        
    def initUI(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.update)
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.open_file)

    def update(self):
        if not self.fname:                                                            
            QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Ошибка!', "Выберите Exсel файл")
            return                                                                  
        excel_file_path = self.fname                             
        worksheet_name = 'Лист1'                                     
        self.loadExcelData(excel_file_path, worksheet_name)

    def open_file(self):
        self.fname, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Выберите файл', '.',  
            "Файлы Exсel (*.xlsx)") 
        print(f'fname = {self.fname}')    
        
    def loadExcelData(self, excel_file_path, worksheet_name):
        df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, worksheet_name)
        if df.size == 0:
            return

        df.fillna('', inplace=True)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(df.shape[0])
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(df.shape[1])
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(df.columns)

        # returns pandas array object
        for row in df.iterrows():
            values = row[1]
            for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
                if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
                    value = '{0:0,.0f}'.format(value)
                tableItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row[0], col_index, tableItem)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 300)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def addRow(self):
        rowPosition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        if not rowPosition:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Выберите Exсel файл для добавления строки.')
            return     
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)

    def delRow(self):
        row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
        if row == -1:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Выберите строку для удаления')
            return
        self.tableWidget.removeRow(row)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    startmenu_window = StartMenuMain()
    windows = QStackedWidget()

    windows.addWidget(startmenu_window)  # 0
    windows.setWindowTitle("")
    windows.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как сделать что бы данные сохранялись именно в файле excel ?

Comment: @grabhar это уже другой вопрос.